# How is Johnson's algorithm not polynomial?

Tags: graph, theory, np-complete

I've read in multiple answers that finding all the cycles in a directed graph is NP-complete, but Johnson's algorithm, which finds all simple cycles in a graph, runs in O((V+E)(C+1)) time (where C is the number of strongly connected components in the graph), which I think is polynomial, since E <= V^2 and C <= V which becomes O(V^3), right?

Johnson's algorithm: http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GA/homeworks/hw1/Johnson%2075.PDF

Comment: Your question is more appropriate for http://cs.stackexchange.com/. See for instance [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59331/is-finding-all-cycles-in-a-graph-using-some-version-of-johnsons-algorithm-code).

Answer (score 0):

According to the PDF you linked, the quantity C here refers not to the number of strongly connected components, but rather to the number of simple cycles in the graph. In other words, the algorithm lists off each of the c simple cycles in the graph, spending at most O(|V| + |E|) time before reporting each of them. Since the number of different simple cycles in a graph can be exponentially large, this algorithm will run in exponential time in the worst-case.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your graph. if your graph is sparse, order of this algorithm is n^2 lgn and if your graph is dense n^3. in total this algorithm is good for sparse graphs.